# Como fazer que um botão que chame um iframe

Tags: iframe, button

No `iframe` abaixo, preciso que ele apenas seja mostrado quando eu clicar em um botão qualquer. Como faço isso?

```
<div>
    <iframe
            width="1100"
            height="500"
            id="iframe"
            src="https://www.google.com.br"
            scrolling="no"
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Esconda o `<iframe>` com CSS (`display:none`)
- Ao clicar no botão, use javascript para exibir, da seguinte forma:

```js
function exibirIframe()
{
    document.getElementById("iframe").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <iframe
            width="1100"
            height="500"
            id="iframe"
            src="https://www.google.com.br"
            scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Exibir Iframe" onclick="exibirIframe();" />
```

*Só uma nota*: páginas como o *google.com.br* não permitirão que outros domínios a utilizem em iframes, por conta de segurança. Isso é feito através do header [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) enviado pelo servidor. Espero que tenha usado essa página só como exemplo.

Comment: Perfeito Marcus Vinicius, muito bom :) Muitíssimo obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Caso queira outra alternativa utilizando jQuery, basta incluir a chamada do código jQuery e incluir ao final do arquivo este trecho de código:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('iframe').hide();
    $('button').click(function ()
    {
        $('iframe').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Acredito que o código acima seja auto-explicativo, porém, se precisar de alguma ajuda ou explicação é só chamar.

Comment: como ficaria com o botão?